# Leaflet Directive - Click event working only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-leaflet-directive

Code :

```
$scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.click', function(event, locationEvent){
    $scope.newLocation = new Location();
    $scope.newLocation.lat = locationEvent.leafletEvent.latlng.lat;
    $scope.newLocation.lng = locationEvent.leafletEvent.latlng.lng;
    $scope.modal.show();
  });
```

Above code shows popup, with current lat & long of user.
But click event works only once, until next reload.

Comment: Did you tried `$scope.modal()` ?

Comment: i am using modal only, but above code is used to get lat & long wherever user click on map